# In React Native, Can I bind swipe/scroll of a SectionList to another View

Tags: animation, react-native, swipe, jsx, expo

I have a SectionList which scrolls/swipes vertically. Can I bind a swipe gesture on it, so that it results in swiping a completely separate View which is behind it? Furthermore, is there an example someone could lead me to, in which a swipe gesture on a SectionList is bound to the animation of another object or objects? Here is a good example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

When the view is scrolled vertically in the example above it causes a menu to animate in from the top. That is close to the desired effect I'm seeking. I'd also love to know how to achieve that rotational animation tied to the horizontal swipe. I'm thinking that I will likely need the Animated API for this kind of behavior. Any tutorials or code examples you have would really help.